# How can I iterate more than 100 blocks in a matrix field for loop?

Tags: templating, matrix, forloop

I am looping through a matrix field and it appears to stop looping when the index reaches 100 but I have more than 100 blocks here. How can I loop through the remaining blocks?

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
    {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default limit for fetching elements is 100. This can be overridden as follows:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField.limit(null) %}
```

Passing in `null` will grab all of them, or you can pass in the specific number you want:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField.limit(400) %}
```