# Matrix field input error from within the control panel

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix field with around 26 block types with between 2-6 fields on each. It seems like I've hit a limit and cannot add any more fields to any of the block types. I can add a field if i delete one.

I get the following error "Undefined index: type"

/var/www/dev/domain.co.uk/craft/app/fieldtypes/MatrixFieldType.php(118)

I'm running Craft Pro 2.1.2563

Matt

Comment: Have you tried upgrading? There have been a fair few Matrix fixes since then. You could upgrade locally first to see if it affects anything else.

Comment: Yes, I tried upgrading this morning but still get the same problem locally. It seems like everything isn't getting posted when saving the matrix field.

Comment: In that case it might be best to submit a support request to P&T through your control panel? They are usually very swift to respond.

Comment: I wonder if it's related to [this issue...](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1404/45) There are a few places around the system with an inherent limit of 100. You say you have 2-6 fields (average 4) per block type... ~25 * ~4 = ~100

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's about a 99% chance you're bumping into your php.ini file's [max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) value and/or its [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size). If you bump those to higher values, it should start working as expected.

Note that you may have to restart your web server for the settings to take affect.

Comment: Cheers Brad, that's fixed the problem, works like a charm.

Comment: Brad for president.

Comment: For nginx users, make sure you run service php5-fpm reload before you restart nginx, the changes did not take affect until I did that. Thanks Brad!

Comment: This solved it! Thanks a lot! I would have never thought of this!

Comment: I set post_max_size to 50 and max_input_vars to 500 . I thoughtthis is enough. We still have problems here...

Comment: Solved it... we have a large Matrix field and I increased max_input_vars to to 1200