# All fields disappearing except 'Title' after saving

Tags: richtext, redactor, debugging

[image: See screenshot]

All other fields disappear except the 'Title' field after I save a large block of text with a lot of links in the body (richtext) field.

I can't seem to pinpoint it on to anything specific, this is what I'm putting inside the 'Source' of the richtext http://pastebin.com/jiyA6xii

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a bug within Craft. I'd recommend submitting a message to Craft support from your dashboard, along with a copy of your database and log files for the guys to look through.

Comment: For what it's worth, I pasted this into a RichText and saved without issue. Do you have devMode turned on? Are you getting any errors in your console or logs upon saving? Logs are found in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`

Comment: See answer here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2777/57

Comment: Check your browser’s JavaScript console. Are you getting any JS errors on the page?

Comment: @brandonKelly `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`

Comment: Do any fields show up in the Meta content tab?

Comment: @brandonKelly Yes sir. It's definitely a PHP setting somewhere, I inserted 500,000 random characters into the body field and it did the same thing.

Comment: In that case it sounds like Brad's comment should point you in the right direction. Did you look into those PHP settings?

Comment: @nicholasodo Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem. Increasing 'max_input_vars' and 'post_max_size' in php.ini is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone wondering, it had to do with the PHP memory limit and max_post_size. If you're coming across this error, increase the limit.

Comment: We encountered this with a large matrix field, where blocktypes near the end would lose all their fields. Bumping `max_post_size` and `max_input_vars` resolved our issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with disappearing fields in the admin interface, and found it seemed to be something to do with the xdebug PHP extension. Disabling that fixed the problem and the fields reappeared:

```
sudo php5dismod xdebug
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The problem in this case is actually to do with reaching a nesting limit, so if you do want to use xdebug, an alternate fix is to bump up the max nesting limit in xdebug's ini file (or php.ini), eg:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

Comment: Worth noting that if you update to xDebug 2.3+, the default value has been increased to 256, instead of 100.