# Matrix field containing asset field blocks entry editing

Tags: matrix, image

I am new to  Craft CMS and am testing it. I encountered a problem.

I have a matrix field, containing an asset field. When I add this matrix field to the page field layout, then visit single entry, put something inside this asset field of the matrix field and save - things break, I can't access this entry in backend later, all that shows is this:

[image: blank page]

I have local assets source set up, and images do upload there, I can see them in assets explorer later.

When I just fill in other fields of matrix field, omitting asset field or don't use matrix field at all, things are ok.

I work on Windows, on XAMPP server.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i found an answer. It seems it was caused by xdebug.

[All fields disappearing except 'Title' after saving](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/3076/all-fields-disappearing-except-title-after-saving)

Adding this to php.ini helped:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```