# No more than 10 blocks in globally used Matrix fields get saved

Tags: matrix

When saving a globally used Matrix field, no more than 10 blocks (**of the same type**) get saved. The Matrix field has no max. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brad Bell: "There's about a 99% chance you're bumping into your php.ini file's max_input_vars value and/or its post_max_size. If you bump those to higher values, it should start working as expected"

[Matrix field input error from within the control panel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/matrix-field-input-error-from-within-the-control-panel/2777#2777)

Comment: Fwiw I just ran into this. The above worked as an initial fix. Eventually you may also need to up your max_execution_time and memory_limit if the matrix is REALLY enormous. Also, if you're working locally keep in mind you'll want to make sure these custom settings are on the server as well.