# Matrix field not saving 200th entry

Tags: matrix

We have a matrix field for weekly winners names in a company promotion. We've entered 199 so far, the 200th is not saving, it blanks out the fields and logs a validation error - cannot save because name is blank.

If we delete item 199 then we can add a new item, it then fails on item 200 again

Is this a known limit in craft matrix fields??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here, it sounds like you are hitting the max_input_vars limit. Strange things happen when you do.

[Matrix field input error from within the control panel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/matrix-field-input-error-from-within-the-control-panel)

Comment: Ah of course, I've had this issue in asp.net sites. What threw us was it happened exactly on number 200 seemed like it must have been a limit.