# Is there a maximum number of fields in a single matrix?

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix with around 75 fields in it. They are spread over multiple "Block Types". When I create a new field and save the matrix, the new fields aren't being saved.

Even worse, when I create a new block type with new fields and then drag it up in the order, when I save, Craft is deleting (trimming) the last fields in the matrix - even though they are old (already created) fields.

Does Craft have a limit on the number of fields in a single matrix?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because of a combination of settings in your `php.ini` file:  `max_input_vars` & `post_max_size`, not any limitation in Craft CMS. c.f.:

[Matrix field input error from within the control panel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/matrix-field-input-error-from-within-the-control-panel)

Comment: This solved my problem on my local development environment as well as on Heroku. For anyone interested, you can modify your php.ini settings by placing a file named .user.ini in the public directory.

Comment: I regularly have this problem when working locally but never encounter it on any remote servers. Probably because my WAMP default settings are too low.

Comment: I noticed I hit a limit on extending a Matrix field’s scope which correlated with `craft_fields` having 255 rows: where 255 was OK but more than 255 was not. 255 seems like a highly significant number, but my `max_input_vars` was set to 1000, so it’s not clear how 255 relates to 1000. Increasing both `max_input_vars` and `post_max_size` worked. Not sure which one made the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Just like **khalwat** said ^^  If you're using MAMP like me, it is in your MAMP Application file MAMP/bin/php/PHP_version_your_using/conf/**php.ini**

It was a combination of upping both **memory_limit** & **post_max_size** to 128M

This did the trick. 
Hope this saves somebody's time.