# Adding a new block type to Matrix causes subfields and subfields of other block types to disappear

Tags: matrix, field, block-types

When saving a newly added block type with subfields to an existing Matrix, the subfields of the new block type are gone and also are the subfields of 6 of the last block types. The whole Matrix contains 29 block types.

I'm using Craft CMS 2.6.2982.

Answer (score 2):

Bumping php.ini's `max_input_vars` to a higher value as described in the answer [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2777/5692) fixed it.