# Editing Entries are not working

Tags: entry, settings

I am not sure if anybody has come across this, but after clicking "Settings" in the Admin Center all of my "Pages" entries are un-editable.  When I click to edit them, all that shows is the title, the "Current" button, and the "Save" button with the drop down disabled.

Here is what I get when I click on a page to edit:[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Do you happen to have xDebug installed on that server?

Comment: I ask because you could be running into this: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2777/57